# Docker with Node.js run -v volume not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, volume

The problem is that in mounting file when I change data in

```
{
  "payload": "UP or down!"
}
```

I didn't get changes on reload http://127.0.0.1:8080/, although I had to get this changes.

I tried 2 ways of mounting volumes to docker but no one is working for me. So I doubt if I do run docker in a proper way.
1 way:

1. mount folder to docker -v absolute path to folder with changes on host machine:absolute path to folder in docker:
2. `docker build -t new .`
3. `docker run --rm --name new3 -p 8080:8080 -e TZ=Europe/Moscow -v E:\PRACTICE\DOCKERS\docker\resources:/usr/src/app/resources new`

When I do all this and run this command, it shows the right content of

```
  "payload": "UP or down!"
```

But when I change this "payload" value I didn't get this new changes on reload in browser.

2 way of do mount volume:

1. Watch, what volumes I have already:

   ```
   docker volumne ls
   ```
2. Create volume:

   ```
   docker volume create web
   ```
3. Build docker image:

   ```
   docker build -t sun .
   ```
4. run with volume:

   ```
   docker run --rm --name sun3 -p 8080:8080 -v web:/usr/src/app/resources sun
   ```

It didn't work. There my docker-project on node.js:

[image]

server.js

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

// константы
const port = 8080;
const host = '0.0.0.0';
const dateNow = new Date().toString();
const resourceData = fs.readFileSync('./resources/response.json');
let response = JSON.parse(resourceData);

// приложение
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // res.send('Hello World');
    // res.send(`This is just string with changes... ${dateNow}`);
    res.send(`${response.payload} ${dateNow}`);
});

app.listen(port, host);
console.log(`running on http://${host}:${port}`);
```

response.json:

```
{
  "payload": "UP or down!"
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

# создание директории приложения
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# установка зависимостей
# символ астериск ("*") используется для того чтобы по возможности
# скопировать оба файла: package.json и package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# Если вы создаете сборку для продакшн
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# копируем исходный код
COPY . .

# EXPOSE декларирует, что можем пробросить порт 8080, но на самом деле не пробрасывает
EXPOSE 8080

# Указываем переменные окружения, в частности, часовой пояс в Докер-image
# ENV TZ Europe/Moscow

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "docker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "node.js on docker",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "docker"
  ],
  "author": "Molchanova Tatyana",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

I searched for this topic, but found nothing.
I have doubt if my docker images is running properly. Please, see my terminal output on running command - if it is ok?

[image]

Why on mounting volume it didn't change output on changing response.json content? The matter is in Path? of in using fs module?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are reading the file only once, when the server starts. You will also notice that `dateNow` will not change if you refresh your browser. You need to move the relevant lines into the `app.get` block. As shown below:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

// константы
const port = 8080;
const host = '0.0.0.0';

// приложение
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // res.send('Hello World');
    // res.send(`This is just string with changes... ${dateNow}`);
    const dateNow = new Date().toString();
    const resourceData = fs.readFileSync('./resources/response.json');
    let response = JSON.parse(resourceData);
    res.send(`${response.payload} ${dateNow}`);
});

app.listen(port, host);
console.log(`running on http://${host}:${port}`);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, Michael, for answer! I remove code to app. The date is now get updated, but changes in response.json in values of "payload" are not applied to output in browser on reload.